# GMLib on android possible?

Tags: gmlib

I would like to know if it is possible to use GMLib for mobile devices using RAD Studio XE7.
Because in the installation file there aren't any information about how to install it for android.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the moment isn't possible to use GMLib from FMX (I'm working in it). However, it is possible that the minimum version of RAD Studio is the XE8

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the answer :) Do you have any ETA on when this future could be available? Just asking because i really need a google maps component(even a minimum one that will use only a map,lines and markers).

Comment: I can't say a line time, now I have a lot of work in my job and I exit very tired. So sorry